# Finding the actual runtime call tree of a Java Program

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, methods, hierarchy

Suppose I have a big program that consists of hundreds of methods in it. And according to the nature of input the program flow is getting changed.

Think I want to make a change to the original flow. And it is big hassle to find call hierarchy/ references and understand the flow.

Do I have any solution for this within Eclipse? Or a plugin? As an example, I just need a Log of method names that is in order of time. Then I don't need to worry about the methods that are not relevant with my "given input"

Update : Using debug mode in eclipse or adding print messages are not feasible. The program is sooooo big. :)

Comment: Do you want the actual call tree that occurred at runtime?  Your question implies that you only want to know what code is relevant for a given input, not what the exact call tree was.

Comment: @ Ira Baxter : Yes, The actual call tree. Thanks for clarifying the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **[AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)** to log the name of all methods called *without* changing your original program.

See **[tracing](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-development.html#tracing)** for instance.

```
aspect SimpleTracing {
    pointcut tracedCall():
        call(void FigureElement.draw(GraphicsContext));

    before(): tracedCall() {
        System.out.println("Entering: " + thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is *what* methods got called, rather than the precise order, you might consider using a test coverage tool.   These tools instrument the source code to collect "this got executed" facts at various degrees of granularity (method call only, and/or every code block controlled by a conditional).

The [SD Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html) is a tool that will do this.

It won't collect the call graph or even the order of the calls.

If you want more control over the instrumentation, you can consider using the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).  DMS will parse, transform, and prettyprint Java in arbitrary ways controlled by custom source-to-source [program transformation](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) rewrite rules.   It would be easy to insert logging transformations into the start and exit of each method (and in fact this is almost exactly how the SD test coverage tool works).   Given the raw  enter-X and exit-X data, constructing the runtime call tree is a straightforward task.