# Determining Order of Method Calls in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Imagine you are handed a Java Eclipse Project. In this project there are a bunch of classes that call methods on each other, pass parameters and get things done, so the classes withing the project are quite interconnected.

Now then, there is one class in particular that you would like to figure out the workings of. Is there a way in Eclipse, through its tools, that would help me figure out the **order in which each of the methods in that particular class are called**?

I am aware that I can do `System.out.println()` inside each of the methods, and monitor the Console output to figure out the order that way, but that is too time consuming for really big classes.

Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: Run in debug mode and step through execution?

Comment: How do you know the order is fixed? Are there no `if` statements and no loops? Surely the order will change depending on the input.

Comment: An interesting [article](http://mathewjhall.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/tracing-java-method-execution-with-aspectj/) about using AspectJ and AOP to do this.

Comment: You could look up the Call Hierarchy and References options of Eclipse in order to get additional help when inspecting the code manually. For a detailed run-time information of your code you could use Aspect4J as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2582906/283084 for logging method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) API of apache. Will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>, you get the Call Hierarchy which lets you know about what methods call this methods and what methods you call (and you can keep navigating over these methods).

References might be very useful too (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much time you want to spend on it, but java agents could help you, as you could hook into the code at runtime and write a monitoring tool.

Another alternative would be to set a breakpoint at some point and then look at the stacktrace.